# Using LINQ to retrieve value from XML (Multiple selection)

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, linq, xelement

I'm trying to convert this VB.Net LINQ to C# LINQ.

Basically, what the end solution is trying to achieve is to to take in an XML file; see snippet:

```
<BasicFee>
        <TrialType>Trial</TrialType>
        <A>1326.85575</A>
        <B>992.409</B>
        <C>668.67075</C>
        <D>1260.50925</D>
        <E>318.8955</E>
        <F>323.30925</F>
        <G>323.30925</G>
        <H>323.44125</H>
        <I>323.169</I>
        <J>1326.85575</J>
        <K>932.877</K>
</BasicFee>
```

And by passing parameters, "Trial" and "B", the result would give me this value "992.409" (result from Trial / B).

---

**EDIT - This VB is not the correct syntax to achieve the result. Please see the accepted answer.**

The VB equivalent is apparently something like this;

```
Dim sResult As String = (From oRecord In oXML.Descendants("BasicFee") Where oRecord.< Name >.Value = "Trial").FirstOrDefault.< B >.Value
```

I have tried tons of different ways and I keep getting the same result (either the Trial element OR the A element values (not being able to use them both).

I was hoping there would be something similar to this:

```
var example = root.Elements("BasicFee").Elements().Where((c=>c.Value == "Trial" && c.Value == "A"));
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Your VB version wouldn't result in anything, there is no `<Name>` element.

Comment: @JeffMercado Thanks, I have since noticed that (i'll edit the question) - after Jon showed me the correct example, it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, your VB example wouldn't work either, but it's pretty simple to do in both languages. You need to distinguish between *names* and *values*, and exactly how your filtering works:

```
var example = root.Elements("BasicFee")
                  .Where(x => (string) x.Element("TrialType") == "Trial")
                  .Select(x => (string) x.Element("B"))
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or with C# 6 you could use:

```
var example = root.Elements("BasicFee")
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => (string) x.Element("TrialType") == "Trial")
                  ?.Element("B")?.Value;
```

The value will be `null` if there's no such element (either no matching `BasicFee` or no `B` element within it).

Comment: Still waiting to accept... After a few hours of trying and you make it look so easy! Thank you!

Comment: Any chance you feel like going the extra mile and giving the same result for VB (for curiosity)?

Comment: @Hexie: I don't know what the most idiomatic VB form would be, but a straight translation of the first form into VB would work fine. (Not sure whether the latest VB has the null conditional operator.)

Answer (score 0):

To find the `BasicFee` that has that trial type and `B` value, in C#:

```
var trialType = "Trial";
var propertyName = "B";
var query = oXML.Descendants("BasicFee")
    .Where(bf => (string)bf.Element("TrialType") == trialType)
    .Select(bf => (string)bf.Element(propertyName))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

The VB version on the other hand, could be written like so:

```
Dim trialType = "Trial"
Dim propertyName = "B"
Dim query =
    (From bf In oXML...<BasicFee> ''// ... equivalent to Descendants
    Where bf.<TrialType>.Value = trialType
    Select bf.Element(propertyName).Value).SingleOrDefault
```